# How can I retrieve the value of a control within an ASP.Net Dynamic Data Custom Field Template?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-dynamic-data

Long story short, for an old project I used ASP.Net Dynamic Data and probably did a terrible job with it.  One of the Field Templates has multiple controls in it, and now I need to get at the value of *one* control from the FormView's Submit event because we changed the way that value is stored.

I can find the Field Template itself using FindFieldTemplate... but I can't figure out how to get to the controls inside of the template.

How can I do that without re-engineering the whole thing to pull that one field out?  It would probably be more correct to re-engineer it, but this is a quick fix for a website that's going to be scrapped in a couple months.

EDIT: Was asked to show code so here it is.  The FormView is pretty standard, just uses an .   The Field Template actually has it's own listview and I'm controlling it's mode in codebehind.  But I need to get the value of txtTitle.

Ticket_TicketMemo.ascx:

```
<asp:ListView   ID="lvTicketMemos" DataSourceID="ldsTicketMemo" 
            InsertItemPosition="FirstItem" OnLoad="lvTicketMemo_Load" runat="server">
<LayoutTemplate>
    <div style="overflow:auto; height:125px; width:600px;">
        <table class="ListViewTable" runat="server">
            <tr id="itemPlaceHolder" runat="server" />
        </table>
    </div>
</LayoutTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
    <tr valign="top" class='<%# Container.DataItemIndex % 2 == 0 ? "" : "Alternate" %>'>
        <td><asp:DynamicControl ID="dcType" DataField="Type" runat="server" /></td>
        <td><asp:DynamicControl ID="dcMemo" DataField="Memo" runat="server" /></td>
        <td><asp:DynamicControl ID="dcCreateTime" DataField="CreateTime" runat="server" /></td>
    </tr>
</ItemTemplate>    
<InsertItemTemplate>
    <tr valign="top">
        <td colspan="3">
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtTitle" Width="99%" Visible="false" OnLoad="txtTitle_Load" runat="server" /><br /><br />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="top">
        <td colspan="3" width="600px">
            <asp:TextBox    ID="txtMemo" Text='<%# Bind("Memo") %>' Width="99%" OnLoad="txtMemo_Load" TextMode="MultiLine" 
                            Rows="5" runat="server" />
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvMemo" Text="Must enter notes" ControlToValidate="txtMemo" runat="server" />
        </td>            
    </tr>
</InsertItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Could you please post some code with `FormView` and your Field Template with controls for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just simulated your problem in my Dynamic Data project. Based on my research (and search) in order to get control value (not from `DynamicControl` value) in Dynamic Data you should implement the following method (i am using this method in my project and i have found one on [Steve blog](http://csharpbits.notaclue.net/), i don't remember full link):

```
/// <summary>
/// Get the control by searching recursively for it.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="Root">The control to start the search at.</param>
/// <param name="Id">The ID of the control to find</param>
/// <returns>The control the was found or NULL if not found</returns>
public static Control FindControlRecursive(this Control Root, string Id)
{
    if (Root.ClientID.IndexOf(Id) > 0)
        return Root;


    foreach (Control Ctl in Root.Controls)
    {
        Control FoundCtl = FindControlRecursive(Ctl, Id);


        if (FoundCtl != null)
            return FoundCtl;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Now, my **EXAMPLE**.

First, my custom `Insert.aspx` page with **FormView** and **EntityDataSource**:

```
<asp:FormView runat="server" ID="FormView1" DataSourceID="DetailsDataSource" DefaultMode="Insert"
    OnItemCommand="FormView1_ItemCommand" RenderOuterTable="false">
    <InsertItemTemplate>
        <table>
            <tr valign="top">
                <td colspan="3">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtTitle" Width="99%" Visible="true" runat="server" /><br />
                    <br />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </InsertItemTemplate>
</asp:FormView>
<asp:EntityDataSource ID="DetailsDataSource" runat="server" EnableInsert="true" OnInserted="DetailsDataSource_Inserted" />
```

Then, **Inserted** event of **EntityDataSource**:

```
protected MetaTable table;
protected void DetailsDataSource_Inserted(object sender, EntityDataSourceChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Exception == null || e.ExceptionHandled)
    {
            string strTitle = String.Empty;
            Control CtlTitle = FormView1.FindControlRecursive("txtTitle");
            if (CtlTitle != null)
            {
                TextBox TextBoxTitle = (TextBox)CtlTitle;
                strTitle = TextBoxTitle.Text;
            }

            Response.Redirect(table.ListActionPath + "?" + "Department_Id=" + strTitle);
    }
}
```

Finally, i enter the text into `txtTitle`, for example, *13* and then i get

[image]